# Returning Segmentation fault codeblocks

Tags: assembly, gcc, raspberry-pi, arm, gnu

I am trying to run this assembly on my raspberry pi 4 but it keeps giving me a seg fault when i run it. I am running this on codeblocks. I have ran the exact same projects that worked but now they keep failing and I don't know why. In this file I am trying to print a statement but it's still not working. It's running the gnu gcc compiler. I've also tried deleting codeblocks and reinstalling but nothing has worked yet

```
    @ for raspberry pi 4
.cpu cortex-a72
.fpu neon-fp-armv8

    @ constants
.data
output: .asciz "Enter first number: "
input: .asciz "%d"
output2: .asciz "\nEnter second number\n"
output3: .asciz "The GCD is: %d\n"

    @ code
.text


    @ Use 2
.align 2

    @ Main function - must be alphanumeric and start with letter or .
.global main
.type main, %function

main:
    mov r4, lr;

        @ print(Enter first number)
    ldr r0, =output;
    bl printf;
```

Answer (score 1):

Register `r4` is a callee saved register.  If you want to use it inside `main` you must `push {r4}` at the start of your function and `pop {r4}` before you return.

Also, your code shown above doesn't return at all.  Did you just forget to post the rest of the program, or does it just run off the end link that?  Running off the end without returning or exiting will certainly produce all kind of errors.